# Install python module on google cloud shell as admin

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to install this module in google cloud shell with a requirements.txt file: https://pypi.org/project/kiteconnect/

However, the installation fails with this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycparser'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

It's a known error with the module that it needs to be pip installed on python3.7 as an admin user:
https://kite.trade/forum/discussion/5131/kiteconnect-installation-issue-for-python-3-7

My question is, how do I pip install this module with admin rights on google cloud shell? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about how Google Cloud works, but can't you `sudo pip install`?

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I just posted it as answer to help future googlers :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Linux-based shell...

Just use `sudo pip install`.

This will run `pip` with admin privileges.